# MTP Integration for Nautilus

Tags: android, arch-linux, nautilus, mtp

How do I setup MTP integration with Nautilus, so when I connect an MTP device I can see it in nautilus and treat it like a regular USB storage device?

I am running ArchLinux / GNOME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had to reboot, it's fixed now.